# Can I use ML Kit in ionic project?

Tags: barcode, google-mlkit, ionic-plugins

The case is that, I want my app to extract barcode data from the provided input image. My project is based on Ionic 3 framework and angular. I was searching for a plugin of MLKit for my project, but didn't get any. Can anyone suggest me some plugins or some other way so that I can work with my input image?

P.S.: I do not want the usual scan of barcode, the use-case will be I will provide an image and the app should read the PDF417 format barcode data.

Thanks!